# How to get python package requirements from another folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, freeze

This is so simple and don't understand why it isn't working.

I have my CMD opened in `folder1`. Its working directory is `folder1`.

```
folder1 --> folder2
```

I have a bunch of `python` files in `folder2`. I would like to obtain its `requirements.txt` file and have it reside within `folder1`.

Again, with my CMD opened in `folder1`, I run `pip freeze --path ./folder2 > requirements.txt`

It returns an empty `requirements.txt` file within `folder1`. If I run `pip freeze` within `folder2` I obtain a list of requirements no problem.

This seems so basic, but why is `--path` not working the way I want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to use `pipreqs`

With `CMD` opened in `folder1`, I ran `pipreqs ./folder2 --savepath requirements.txt`

A `requirements.txt` file appeared in `folder1`. The packages were based on the `python` files in `folder2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing project folders with where pip installs it's site-packages. This is what the --path parameter refers to. Since you don't seem to be familiar with virtual environments, you don't have any and your 2 project folders are using exactly the same packages and you get the requirements.txt simply by

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This is not different for your 2 project folders.

Answer (score 0):

What `pip freeze` outputs is the list of packages that he things are installed. Usually it just reads `site-packages`. The `path` parameter just restricts which packages it should listed, so you are saying *take all site-packages from folder 1 and restrict them to this under folder2*, which obviously returns empty list.

What you want to do is run proper pip - I guess you have some **virtualenv** under `folder2`, so it would be `folder2/<your venv>/bin/pip freeze`. If you havent, than actually all things you installed via `pip` lands into the same, global `site-packages`, so you won't be able to filter only this used by files in `folder2`.